# BannerView Nil when calling function from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting nil when unwrapping an optional value with GADBannerView..

I setup my ad banner like this, in FlashViewController.swift..

```
class FlashViewController: UIViewController { 
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
```

and then in ViewDidLoad:

```
  func initAdMobBanner() {
  bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
   bannerView.rootViewController = self
   bannerView.load(GADRequest())
  }
```

bannerView has an outlet in storyboard to Root View Controller, which is class FlashViewController.

Then in TableViewController.swift I have my purchase button. Purchase button runs:

```
 FlashViewController().HideMyBanner();
```

The function HideMyBanner is in FlashViewController and will run this code:

```
if bannerView != nil {
        print("bannerview Contains a value!")
        bannerView.isHidden = true

    } else {
        print("bannerview Doesn’t contain a value.")
    }
```

The issue is, if I create a button directly in FlashViewContorller.swift and run the same function, bannerView contains a value and can be hidden.. If I call the function from TableViewController.swift, it returns nil, (or crashes if I try to hide bannerView... I feel like I missing something easy here, but already spent a long time trying to figure it out...

Comment: how you set up navigation of FlashViewContorller to TableViewController?

Comment: I used SWRevealViewController custom segue sw_front goes to FlashViewController and sw_right goes to TableViewController, so you can swipe between the two views...

Comment: Your code in the table view controller is creating a new instance of FlashViewController and hiding the banner view on that; but this view controller is not onscreen. This new ViewController is then thrown away. If you are setting up a "disable ads" purchase, then you need to persist this purchase somewhere (such as keychain) and then check this in `FlashViewController`

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: I set purchase to yes in userDefaults ... I check for this on Load of FlashViewController (when the app boots up) the issue is I need to remove the ads immediately after the purchase is made (on the TableViewController view)

Comment: checkout my anther answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Notifications to finally work this out... Controller 2 sends a notification that a purchase has been made, and Controller 1 observes and waits for this notification, then takes care of hiding the banner in Controller 1.

https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/pass-data-with-nsnotification-in-swift-3-73743723c84b

Answer (score 0):

By using this line `FlashViewController().HideMyBanner();` you are creating new object of `FlashViewController`. so it will crash.you need to use the object of `FlashViewController` which is already created and loaded in memory.

I think you need to pass the reference of `FlashViewContorller` to `TableViewController`

If your `TableViewController` is load from `FlashViewContorller` than you need to create reference `FlashViewContorller` in `TableViewController` like this way.

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    var objFlashViewContorller : FlashViewContorller?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //This is the UILabel

    }

    func purchasebuttonClick() {
        objFlashViewContorller?.HideMyBanner();
    }
}
```

While setup Navigation FlashViewContorller to TableViewController you need to pass reference.

```
let tableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as! TableViewController
tableViewController.objFlashViewContorller = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: true)
```

**OR**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TableViewController" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
            vc.objFlashViewContorller = self
        }
```

Comment: Not sure about the setup Navigation FlashViewController to TableViewController - where does this code live? right now open source library RevealViewController handles the segue... it already animates...

Comment: where to put the override func?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FlashViewController().HideMyBanner();`

I think you need to use this in  in TableViewController.swift -> my purchase button method.

```
self.revealViewController.frontViewController.HideMyBanner()
```

Comment: It won't build... It says revealViewController was used a property and I should add () to it..  But I was always able to run the function HideMyBanner that lives in FlashViewController from TableViewController... however it just breaks if I make any reference to bannerView.... Even though another function in FlashViewController uses bannerView just fine...

Comment: your issue is very simple you need to get reference of FlashViewController from revealViewController any how.  i have no siwft code so i can't write syntax properly. in objective c  code for get the frount view controller 
UINavigationController *nv = (UINavigationController *) self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    NSLog(@"navigation  %@",nv.viewControllers[0]);